# ループでDOM要素を追加し終えたら、そのタイミングで次の処理をしたい

Tags: javascript

**ループでDOM要素を追加しているのですが、処理終了判定はどう実装するのでしょうか？**
・Promise？

・下記のような感じで、appendChildしている箇所が複数あるのですが、これは非同期処理に該当するのでしょうか？
・Ajaxとか特に使用していないように思うのですが…

```
for (var i = wrap_col.length; i < active_col; i++){
        var new_col = wrap_col[0].cloneNode(true);
        new_col.innerHTML = '';
        this_wrap.appendChild(new_col);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 同期処理

int32_t さんの回答通り、`appendChild` は同期処理なので、forループを抜けた後に後続処理を書けば、同期的に連続処理されます。

```
for (var i = wrap_col.length; i < active_col; i++){
  var new_col = wrap_col[0].cloneNode(true);
  new_col.innerHTML = '';
  this_wrap.appendChild(new_col);
}
console.log('次の処理');
```

なお、同期処理されるのはDOMツリーにノードを追加するところまでなので、CSSの適用、外部リソース(画像ファイル等)のダウンロード等は非同期処理で行われます。

## コードの改善点

余談ですが、コード上にいくつか改善点があるので指摘しておきます。

- `cloneNode(true)` した後に `innerHTML` で子ノード群を削除していますが、それならば初めから `cloneNode(false)` で子ノードを複製しなければ良いでしょう。
- DocumentFragment を使えば、appendChild は一回で済みます。
- `new_col` は毎回同じノードを cloneNode していますが、雛形となるノードを変数にキャッシュする事で効率化できます

コードは次のようになります。

```
var var new_col = wrap_col[0].cloneNode(false), df = new_col.ownerDocument.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = wrap_col.length; i < active_col; i++){
  df.appendChild(new_col.cloneNode(false));
}
this_wrap.appendChild(df);
console.log('次の処理');
```

Re: re9 さん

Comment: コード改善点の件、なるほどと思いました。大変参考になりました

Answer (score 1):

> ループでDOM要素を追加しているのですが、処理終了判定はどう実装するのでしょうか？

そのまま、`for` ループを抜ければ終了したことになります。

> 下記のような感じで、appendChildしている箇所が複数あるのですが、これは非同期処理に該当するのでしょうか？

`appendChild` は同期処理です。

追加したノードが画面に描画されるタイミングは、非同期であったり特定のAPIで同期されたり、色々です。

Comment: 「for ループを抜ければ終了したことになります」の意味は「for文終了判定」の意味ですか？　for内の全ての処理が終了とは連動しない？　また、「appendChild は同期処理」と「追加したノードが画面に描画されるタイミング」 の違いが分からないのですが、両者は別物なのでしょうか？